# PHP Data Validation/Input Security

Tags: php, mysql

Im just working on imrpoving the secuity of my system before it goes live. So im adding a function to validate input data.
I found this here on the w3c webseite as i did some research on whats the best way.

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

As most stuff is Safed in a Database I also require a MySql Escape Which i already had implemented. Now i would like to merge this and i just wonder in which order I run through those steps. 
It sure makes sense to `trim` first but following that? Im specialy not sure abot `stripslashes` and `MySql Escape` as its kind of reversing itself?

It would be nice if somone with more Experience could shine some light on it for me!

Edit 1: What is about Numeric Inputs - Is it 'enough' to test with `is_numeric()`?

Comment: Dont use `mysql_` functions anymore. Use `mysqli` functions or `PDO` functions. Then use parameterized queries.

Comment: @chris85 Ok I was thinking about it earlier but I might reconsider it as it seems to be the future as i just seen it is going to be removed in PHP 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to validate your data. However without knowing what the purpose of the data is, it's impossible to advise on how to validate it. Validation & input security is about applying principles properly rather than any one specific set of code that fixes all potential issues. If it was that easy then SQL injection would not be top of the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013).

What you must do is always ensure the data matches what you expect. For example a text string in a numeric field could cause your code to do unexpected things. PHP has many functions that can be used for validation. `is_numeric`, `strlen` and `preg_match` - regular expressions are great for validating dates, zip codes and a host of other input.

I'm not sure why you are using `stripslashes`, esp. when talking about database queries. It was once common to see `addslashes` in use, so much so that PHP had [magicquotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) to automatically `addslashes` on all input. It's worth reading [those pages of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) as they cover the issues of blanket changing all input very well.

The 2nd thing to do is decide how you want to handle input that does not match expectations. It may be worth logging the errors so you can resolve any issues with your front end code. Are you going to let the user know that there was a problem with the input?

Final thought on your question, you are asking about validating the input, but `stripslashes` and `htmlspecialchars` both modify the input as well. This can create issues later on, for example if you happen to want slashes in your input data for some use cases or the input is an image and not text.

Have different validation for different input types. Keep the encoding/escaping code to use when required. E.g. `mysqli->real_escape_string` before db inserts and `htmlspecialchars` before using the data in xhtml output.

Read around the issue, learn the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013), ask on S.O. if you are struggling on a particular input scenario. Apply the lessons and the monitor your application in the real world. Don't just assume it will be secure and you will go a long way to avoiding the pain & embarrassment of fixing a hacked system.